# How to exit in Node.js

Tags: node.js

What is the command that is used to exit? (i.e terminate the Node.js process)

Comment: there's a how-to here: https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-exit-from-a-nodejs-program

Answer (score 2851, accepted):

Call the global [`process`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html) object's [`exit`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) method:

```
process.exit()
```

[From the docs:](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_exit_codes)

> ### `process.exit([exitcode])`
>
> Ends the process with the specified `code`. If omitted, exit with a 'success' code `0`.
>
> To exit with a 'failure' code:
>
> ```
> process.exit(1);
> ```
>
> The shell that executed node should see the exit code as `1`.

Comment: Just want to add something. If you are handling a request, you should also `end()` the request as well. Otherwise, it'll just hang.

Comment: @pixelfreak, `exit` isn't misleading at all.  You are confused about how Node works.  Think of Node as the server itself.  It isn't just fired up as needed, like PHP is within a web server like Apache.  Node doesn't even have to have anything to do with web servers at all!  It's just a host for some JavaScript, with some nifty built-in libraries for doing useful things.

Comment: @Brad And PHP is a general purpose language. No need to run it with `mod_php` or use Apache. You can reimplement an httpd in PHP like node does if you really want or use a more sane/standardized approach like FastCGI just like you can in node.

Comment: Please note that `process.exit()` is **not recommended**, as described in [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37592669/199263).

Comment: Off-topic slightly, but I've seen people use `process.exit(-1)`. Why's that?

Comment: @PiggyPlex Did you get an answer why people use exit with -1 ?

Comment: @Vipulw see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61571571/node-js-process-exit-1

Comment: I imagine `-1` would be an unknown failure.

Answer (score 643):

Just a **note** that using `process.exit([number])` is [not recommended](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processexitcode) practice.

> Calling `process.exit()` will force the process to exit as quickly as
> possible even if there are still asynchronous operations pending that
> have not yet completed fully, including I/O operations to
> `process.stdout` and `process.stderr`.
>
> In most situations, it is not actually necessary to call
> `process.exit()` explicitly. The Node.js process will exit on its own if
> there is no additional work pending in the event loop. The
> `process.exitCode` property can be set to tell the process which exit
> code to use when the process exits gracefully.
>
> For instance, the following example illustrates a **misuse** of the
> `process.exit()` method that could lead to data printed to `stdout` being
> truncated and lost:
>
> ```
> // This is an example of what *not* to do:
> if (someConditionNotMet()) {
>   printUsageToStdout()
>   process.exit(1)
> }
> ```
>
> The reason this is
> problematic is because writes to `process.stdout` in Node.js are
> sometimes asynchronous and may occur over multiple ticks of the
> Node.js event loop. Calling `process.exit()`, however, forces the
> process to exit before those additional writes to `stdout` can be
> performed.
>
> Rather than calling `process.exit()` directly, the code should set the
> `process.exitCode` and allow the process to exit naturally by avoiding
> scheduling any additional work for the event loop:
>
> ```
> // How to properly set the exit code while letting
> // the process exit gracefully.
> if (someConditionNotMet()) {
>   printUsageToStdout()  
>   process.exitCode = 1
> }
> ```

### TLDR

Set the exit code (non zero means error) e.g. `process.exitCode = 1` instead of forcing the process to terminate with `process.exit(1)` which can cause async code to ungracefully terminate (e.g. you can miss `stdout`).

In most cases you'll need to stop some event loop, e.g. the server HTTP loop. Which you can exit if the `exitCode` is non-zero:

```
if (someConditionNotMet()) {
  printUsageToStdout()
  process.exitCode = 1
}

// In your loop
if (process.exitCode > 0) {
  break
}
```

Once your loops aren't running Node will gracefully exit.

Comment: This is the best answer, by far. Other answers might not allow node to properly process pending events before exit, very sad :(

Comment: Agreed, this should have more upvotes!  I had a node script that was kicking off multiple child processes via shelljs.exec and I wanted my overall script to return with an error exit code if any of the child processes failed.  process.exitCode = 1 worked great in the exec callbacks (whereas simply calling process.exit(1) in there would exit the main script before all child processes finished!)

Comment: I used this answer and found that my process never actually exited. Had to ctrl-C it.

Comment: Then I'd imagine something is keeping it open - if you do `echo "console.log('hello')" >> ./test.js && node test.js` you should see it print hello and then exit

Comment: If you fork a child process you MUST `child.disconnect();` for `process.exitCode=0` (or `1`) to take affect. Not disconnecting will cause your program to hang. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_disconnect

Comment: There are many uses cases for immediate process and pending event termination. That is exactly what `process.exit()` is intended for.

Comment: This is not the best answer by any stretch because it doesn't answer the question. Instead, it gives best practices on how to develop code flow for a nodejs program.

Comment: Hence why the answer is prefixed with "Just a note"

Comment: Please be aware that referenced documentation is for version 9. This may not equally apply for previous versions of NodeJS.

Comment: Actually this quote is from Jun 2016 and the docs still haven't changed for v9 :)

Comment: This showed me that my express server wasn't safely exiting and probably saved me from tracking down an annoying issue of truncated data due to forced termination of a mid-process thread. Definitely use this over the function and safely clean up your long-living objects. Took like 3 minutes to fix, who knows how long a truncated data issue would have taken for me to realize why it happened.

Comment: But if you are working with async/await and controlling your event loops, if you need to exit the app you should know at this point nothing else is waiting to be executed in the next tick. I agree it's not right to have this when you run an express for example, but if your run a script, you can totally do it properly by your hands.
About the express, I'm sure there is a way to wait for a signal closing the socket and then you can fire up the exit

Comment: This question probably comes up a lot with people not understand how async operations work. They start something, like listening on a socket, and then never close it. They leave DB connections open. And then the complaint is `it's not closing! so I need to force it`. Basically, if you are reading this, chances are you are doing something wrong.

Comment: If you run `process.exit(1)` after an operation like console.log or console.error, is there a chance that the program will exit before the data is sent to the console? Does this only affect asynchronous processes?

Comment: @Dominic I really appreciate this note. I think what would tie it to the question more and provide a better answer is add how a person would go about finding what is keeping node running. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337780/how-can-i-find-out-why-nodejs-isnt-exiting-cleanly, https://github.com/mafintosh/why-is-node-running or process._getActiveHandles()

Comment: Imagine you want to leave expressjs server. How can this work?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira [`close`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback) the server then. It won't receive new connections, and once you are done processing all of the existing requests (at which point the callback fires), shut down your database connections of whatever else you have. Once nothing is left, the process will exist. [For instance this is what you'd do as reaction to `SIGTERM` to allow a process manager to shut down the server gracefully](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/healthcheck-graceful-shutdown.html).

Comment: But do you really want to keep your node process alive to process other ticks if "some condition has not been met", i.e., your program has reached an unexpected state?

Comment: process.exitCode is not a workable solution when you have more than one exit scenario in your application. You can set exitCode = 1 in one spot and trigger a second assignment elsewhere, and then you're either accidentally getting a 0 exit code or a 2 exitCode that is not the proximal cause of the program failure.

Answer (score 404):

From the official [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/api/) documentation:

```
process.exit(code)
```

Ends the process with the specified code. If omitted, exit uses the 'success' code 0.

To exit with a 'failure' code:

```
process.exit(1);
```

Comment: Could `process.exit(code=0)` be rewritten as `code = 0; process.exit(0)`?

Comment: @Alison yes, or more precisely `code = 0; process.exit(code);`

Comment: Is it true that if you're exiting, you probably don't care about the value of `code`?

Comment: You can always yourself determine, depending on that you don't override an already existing error code, where the program exited and with which error code.

Comment: So funny, I tried with all exit, quit, end, stop but none of them worked, and the correct one is yours :D. Thanks.

Comment: @Alison A better idea is just `process.exit()` with no parameter as code defaults to 0

Comment: @Armand You are correct -- Code is just a variable, and in this case used to indicate what the parameter is.  So .exit(0) does everything the example does.

Comment: @Armand the code is not for you, it's for whatever ran your code.  For example, if you create an exit_0.js with `process.exit(0);` and run it with `node exit_0.js && echo 'success'` it will say "success".  If you create exit_1.js with `process.exit(1);` and run `node exit_1.js && echo 'success'` it will not say "success" since your process exited with a non-zero (which indicates a "failure" or "abnormal exit" to the shell).  In addition, you will see different values in `$?` if you run `node exit_1.js` vs `node exit_0.js` (you can check by doing `node exit_1.js` and then doing `echo $?`).

Answer (score 295):

If you're in a Unix terminal or Windows command line and want to exit the Node REPL, either...

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> twice, or
- type `.exit` and press Enter, or
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> at the start of a line (Unix only)

Comment: Note that, beyond Node, the Ctrl+D shortcut on Mac or Linux works on almost all shells and REPLs you'll ever encounter, including Unix shells like Bash, the shells for databases like MySQL and PostgreSQL, and the REPLs for programming languages like Python, PHP, and Ruby. It is the only method of exiting shells I ever use.

Comment: For the `node` REPL, Ctrl+D to exit is a standard behavior, so it also works on Windows.

Comment: Press Ctrl + C (even on a Mac!)

Answer (score 135):

From the command line, `.exit` is what you want:

```
$ node
> .exit
$
```

It's documented in the [REPL docs](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html). REPL (Read-Eval-Print-Loop) is what the Node command line is called.

From a normal program, use [`process.exit([code])`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code).

Answer (score 101):

It depends on the reason why you're willing to exit node.js process, but in any case `process.exit()` is the **last option to consider**. A quote from documentation:

> It is important to note that calling `process.exit()` will force the
>   process to exit as quickly as possible even if there are still
>   asynchronous operations pending that have not yet completed fully,
>   including I/O operations to `process.stdout` and `process.stderr`.
>
> In most situations, it is not actually necessary to call
>   `process.exit()` explicitly. The Node.js process will exit on it's own
>   if there is no additional work pending in the event loop. The
>   `process.exitCode` property can be set to tell the process which exit
>   code to use when the process exits gracefully.

Let’s cover possible reasons why you might be willing to exit node.js process and why you should avoid `process.exit()`:

### Case 1 - Execution complete (command line script)

If script has reached its end and node interpreter doesn't exit, it indicates that some async operations are still pending. It’s wrong to force process termination with `process.exit()` at this point. It’s better to try to understand [what is holding your script from exiting in expected way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057328/node-js-inspect-whats-left-in-the-event-loop-thats-preventing-the-script-from). And when you settle this, you can use `process.exitCode` to return any result to calling process.

### Case 2 - Termination because of external signal (SIGINT/SIGTERM/other)

For example, if you’re willing to gracefully shut down an **express** app. Unlike command line script, express app keeps running infinitely, waiting for new requests. `process.exit()` will be a bad option here because it’s going to interrupt all requests which are in pipeline. And some of them might be non-idempotent (UPDATE, DELETE). Client will never know if those requests are completed or not on server side and it might be the reason of data inconsistency between client and server. The only good solution is to tell http server to stop accepting new requests and wait for pending ones to finish with `server.close()`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(80);

process.on( 'SIGTERM', function () {
   server.close(function () {
     console.log("Finished all requests");
   });
});
```

If it still doesn't exit - see Case 1.

### Case 3 - Internal error

It's always better to `throw` an error, you’ll get a nicely formatted stack trace and error message. Upper levels of code can always decide if they can handle error (`catch`) or let it crash the process. On the other side, `process.exit(1)` will terminate process silently and there will be no chance to recover from this. It might be the only “benefit” of `process.exit()`, you can be sure that process will be terminated.

Comment: Amazing response. `Process.exit()` looks like major overkill for most applications. I was looking for an equivalent to php's die() function... more like: `throw new Error('die msg')`

Comment: If one has a bunch of code which is supposed to execute continuously until a shutdown request is received, is there any nice convention for registering events that would allow subscriptions to be abandoned in response to a shutdown request, without that requiring the code using the events or the code requesting the shutdown have specific knowledge about each other?  Unfortunately, the only way I can think of to kinda-sorta implement that would be to require that any piece of code that registers an event also create a wrapper which includes a closure to unregister it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It explains `process.exit()`, `process.exitCode`, signal handling and (what I want) `throw new Error` to exit.

Answer (score 32):

**REPL**(Command Line)

- Press `ctrl + c`  **twice**
- Type `.exit` and press enter

**Script File**

```
process.exit(code)
```

Node normally exits with **code 0** when no more async operations are pending.

`process.exit(1)` should be used to exit with a failure code.This will allow us to infer that node didn't close gracefully and was forced to close.

There are other exit codes like

3 - Internal JavaScript Parse Error ( very very rare)

5 - Fatal error in v8 javascript engine

9 - Invalid argument

For full list see [node exit codes](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_exit_codes)

Answer (score 15):

I have an application which I wanted to:

1. Send an email to the user
2. Exit with an error code

I had to hook `process.exit(code)` to an `exit` event handler, or else the mail will not be sent since calling `process.exit(code)` directly kills asynchronous events.

```
#!/usr/bin/nodejs
var mailer = require('nodemailer');
var transport = mailer.createTransport();
mail = {
  to: 'Dave Bowman',
  from: 'HAL 9000',
  subject: 'Sorry Dave',
  html: 'Im sorry, Dave. Im afraid I cant do <B>THAT</B>.'
}
transport.sendMail(mail);
//process.exit(1);
process.on('exit', function() { process.exit(1); });
```

Comment: I think you want [process.exitCode](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exitcode)

Comment: For the record: I spent a good chunk of the day trying to get `process.exitCode` to work for me in a command-line tool I'm building (tested on Node v4.3.0).  But I couldn't get it to behave as documented.  This very well could have been an edge case with `commander`- although https://github.com/tj/commander.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=process.exitCode makes me wonder.  Not sure if anyone else out there's seen this problem w/ Node 4, but documenting just in case for future reference.

Comment: re the possibility of this coming from commander, I also looked at its only dep (https://github.com/zhiyelee/graceful-readlink/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=process.exitCode+OR+process.exit&type=Code) but no dice.  Only possible culprit seems like maybe: https://github.com/tj/commander.js/blob/c6236d9504b60d9a2e6aa7fc3ce17a12f48f4a3e/index.js#L554  Specifically, the issue is that, even if you set `process.exitCode = 1`, the process exits with code 0.

Answer (score 13):

As @Dominic pointed out, [throwing an uncaught error](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) is better practice instead of calling *process.exit([code])*:
`process.exitCode = 1;
throw new Error("my module xx condition failed");`

Comment: Taken in context of the question "How to exit in Node.js", this is horrible advice. Your suggestion would make much more sense if the question were specifically asking how to exit on error. I strongly suggest that you word your response in such a way as to indicate that the user do as you suggest, only if they are trying to exit the application in the event of an *error*.

Comment: @rstackhouse, I hope you have gone through __throwing an uncaught error__ which points to --> https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code

Comment: The problem with throwing is the ugly as hell stack trace. Any tip to avoid this stack trace (not relevant when CLI tool wants to exit if usage is not correct)?

Answer (score 12):

Press `Ctrl + C` twice 
or `.exit`.

```
> 
(To exit, press ^C again or type .exit)
>
```

Answer (score 11):

To exit

```
let exitCode = 1;
process.exit(exitCode)
```

Useful exit codes

```
1 - Catchall for general errors
2 - Misuse of shell builtins (according to Bash documentation)
126 - Command invoked cannot execute
127 - “command not found”
128 - Invalid argument to exit
128+n - Fatal error signal “n”
130 - Script terminated by Control-C
255\* - Exit status out of range
```

Comment: Consider updating your answer, https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code

Answer (score 8):

From code you can use `process.exit([errorcode])` where `[errorcode]` is an optional integer (`0` is the default to indicate success).

If you're using the [Read Eval Print Loop (REPL)](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html), you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, or type `.exit`

Alternatively, on Windows or Linux you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

On Mac the command is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

Comment: Two control c's works on the mac, too, at least on mine with 

`node --version`

`v0.10.18`

Comment: Control-C doesn't appear to cancel operations that were already scheduled, whereas ctrl-z kills the process without delay, on Mac.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get all my node processes to die directly from the Git Bash shell on Windows 10 by typing `taskkill -F -IM node.exe` - this ends all the node processes on my computer at once. I found I could also use `taskkill //F //IM node.exe`. Not sure why both `-` and `//` work in this context. Hope this helps!

Comment: That's due to taskkill itself. You are killing processes themselves. Also, a single / is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Open the command line terminal where node application is running and press **Ctrl + C**

if you want to exit a node js application from code,

```
process.exit(); // graceful termination 
process.exit(1); // non graceful termination
```

Comment: `process.exit` is _never_ graceful. Omitting the code will just use `process.exitCode ?? 0` instead.

Answer (score 3):

As process is global object, you don't need to import any module. The following function exits or kills the current node process.

> process.exit(code)
>
> process.kill(process.pid)
>
> process.abort()

Answer (score 1):

### The exit in node js is done in two ways:

- Calling **process.exit()** explicitly.
- Or, if nodejs event loop is done with all tasks, and there is nothing left to do. Then, the node application will automatically exit.

#### How it works?

If you want to force the execution loop to stop the process, yo can use the global variable **process** which is an instance of **EventEmitter**. So when you call ***process.exit()*** you actually emit the **exit** event that ends all tasks immediately even if there still are asynchronous operations not been done.

**process.exit()** takes an exit code (Integer) as a parameter. The code **0** is the default and this means it exit with a 'success'. While the code **1** means it exit with a 'failure'.

Answer (score 1):

```
import mongosse from 'mongoose'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import colors from 'colors'
import users from './data/users.js'
import products from './data/products.js'
import User from './models/userModel.js'
import Product from './models/productModel.js'
import Order from './models/orderModel.js'
import connectDB from './config/db.js'

dotenv.config()

connectDB()

const importData = async()=>{
try{
    await Order.deleteMany()
    await Product.deleteMany()
    await User.deleteMany()

    const createdUsers = await User.insertMany(users)
    const adiminUser = createdUsers[0]._id

    sampleProducts = products.map(product =>{
        return {...product, user:adiminUser }
    })
    await Product.insertMany(sampleProducts)

    console.log('Data Imported!'.green.inverse)
    process.exit()      //success and exit

}catch(error){
    consolele.log(`${error}`.red.inverse)
    process.exit(1)   //error and exit

}

}
```

so here im populating some collections in a db and in the try block if i dont get any errors then we exit it with a success message , so for that we use process.exit() with nothing in the parameter.
If theres an error then we need to exit with an unsuccessfull message so we pass 1 in the parameter like this , process.exit(1).

extra: Here by exiting we mean exiting that typical node js program. eg if this code was in a file called dbOperations.js then the process.exit will exit and wont run any code that follows after process.exit

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate present process
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> twice is to exit REPL shell
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to exit from REPL SHELL

Answer (score 0):

You may use [process.exit([code])](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) function.

If you want to exit without a 'failure', you use code `0`:

```
process.exit(0);
```

To exit with a 'failure' code `1` you may run:

```
process.exit(1);
```

The 'failure' code of the failure is specific to the application. So you may use your own conventions for it.

Answer (score 0):

To terminate the Node.js process, you can use the `process.exit()` command. This command instructs Node.js to exit immediately, terminating the current process.

`process.exit();`

By default, `process.exit()` will exit the process with a code of 0, indicating successful termination. However, you can also pass an exit code as an argument to indicate different exit statuses. For example:

`process.exit(1);` Exits with a code of 1, indicating an error

Please note that using `process.exit()` should be done with caution, as it immediately terminates the process without allowing any pending asynchronous operations to complete. It's generally recommended to handle clean-up tasks and gracefully shut down the process when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you just have to press CTRL + C

Answer (score -5):

If you're in Windows, go to Task Manager, then go to Processes, look for a process called "node", then click on it with the right button of your mouse and then click the "End Process" option.

Comment: This is irrelevant with consideration to the question context. not windows processes but programmatically exiting a given execution in a node function

Comment: This is irrelevant with consideration to the question context. not windows processes but programmatically exiting a given execution in a node function