# Node.js as a server script

Tags: node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to exit in Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266152/how-to-exit-in-node-js)

I'm using node.js to import some data in the background and I'll have the script running every other day in the background using cron. I don't need it to listen. How do I exit the node script after it runs? Should I use process.exit() or is there a better way?

Comment: It will end automatically when there is no more to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not bound to a database or listing on a port it will automatically close. If you are connected to a database and need to shut down the process then use `process.exit();` after cleaning up the connections.

Comment: Close the connection to the database properly and do not use `process.exit()`.