# execute node.js without using command prompt(either winform or javascript)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am Totally new to Node.js, i have a node app running, but now i need to execute the node.js program without using command prompt atall. It maybe through winform app(using vb.net) or using javascript.

Can somebody help me out on this?

Cheers
Jeev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I blogged about how to create a standalone EXE for NodeJS apps here:
http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/blog/development/create-a-standalone-exe-to-run-a-node-js-application

You're not really running the app through a separate app.
Node is an executable that runs the Javascript code - this just packages the required application, along with your code, to give the impression of it running standalone.

Comment: I have a query here, it's definitely running the node.js, but if i want to shut it down, i have to manually close the cmd prompt(which even i forgot to mention in my question) , is this anyhow possible to stop node.js on a button click like event???

Comment: try using process.exit - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266152/how-to-exit-in-node-js

Comment: where is this process.exit added?? to the batch file or in js file??

Comment: you'd put that in the js file. Look at this for commands you could use in the bat file http://www.robvanderwoude.com/exit.php

Answer (score 1):

Two other cross-platform options to check out are [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) and [AppJS](http://appjs.org/)