# How to know what blocks NodeJS from closing

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I have code that runs on NodeJS which involves intervals, sockets, and other async things.

Sometimes when it should close, it hangs forever, presumably since somewhere under some circumstances, I forget to clear an interval, close a socket, or something else.

Is there a way to get the currently active timers, and other such runtime information? Or inspect in any kind of way what blocks the exit?

Comment: Yeah, a debugger.

Comment: I tried searching for information under the global process object, but couldn't find anything there. Any hints? :)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use `process.exit()` when you want your program to exit?

Comment: process.exit() seems very hacky to me, no other reason really.

Comment: It's not hacky at all.  It's a core concept of nearly any program in any OS.  The program tells the OS when it's done and wants to exit.  All node.js is doing with all its timer and socket counters is just trying to decide when to call the same function to cause the program to exit.  If it's clear to you when you're done with everything and you want your program to exit, just call `process.exit()`.

Comment: Thing is, my code is used as a library, and thus it shouldn't really control when the event loop ends - only clean itself up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/wtfnode from a related question to this one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38471228/2503048). Oddly enough I couldn't find this information when googling. It should probably answer my question. Mostly the part about `process._getActiveHandles()`.