# Handle Node.js spawnSync errors

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, spawn

I'm trying to run "npm publish" from a gulp task. It works, but I want to handle any error that npm command itself throws.

If I execute this code:

```
var cmd = spawnSync('npm.cmd', ['publish', packageDir], { stdio: 'inherit' })
```

**cmd.stdout** and **cmd.stderr** are null. If I execute

```
var cmd = spawnSync('npm.cmd', ['publish', packageDir], { stdio: 'pipe' })
```

**cmd.stdout** and **cmd.stderr** are buffers, like  `<Buffer 6e 70 6d 20 45 52...`

What am I missing here?

Comment: If I do this `cmd.stderr.toString()`, I can see the error, but **cmd,error** is still undefined...

Answer (score 10):

In Node documentation regarding `options.stdio` it says

> By default, the child's stdin, stdout, and stderr are redirected to
>   corresponding subprocess.stdin, subprocess.stdout, and
>   subprocess.stderr.

In your options use

```
{ stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', 'pipe'] }
```

And then check for `stderr`. An example:

```
var spawn = childProcess.spawnSync('node myScript.js', { stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', 'pipe'] })

if (spawn.stderr) {
  console.log(Error(spawn.stderr))
  process.exitCode = 1;
}
```

Comment: Just a note, `process.exit` is not recommended. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37592669/4017403) before copy-pasting

Answer (score 0):

Fixing some of the issues with a previous answer. Here is how I was able to get it to work properly:

```
const npmInstall = spawnSync(
  "npm",
  ["install"],
  { stdio: ["inherit", "inherit", "pipe"] }
);

if (npmInstall.stderr.toString().trim()) {
  console.error(`${errorPrefix}${npmInstall.stderr.toString()}`);
} else {
  console.log("NPM Install Complete.");
}
```