# What is difference between method process.exit(1) and process.exit(0) in node.js?

Tags: node.js

In node.js applications i saw usage of both these methods `process.exit(1)` and `process.exit(0)`. Can anybody give me the exact answer ?

Comment: This is simply the exit status of the progress. You may be interested in reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status and https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html for general information about exit codes.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

> Node normally exits with a 0 status code when no more async operations
>   are pending. There are other exit codes which are described below:
>
> **1 - Uncaught Fatal Exception**: There was an uncaught exception, and it was not handled by a domain or an uncaughtException event handler.
>
> **2 - Unused**: Reserved by Bash for built in misuse.
>
> **3 - Internal JavaScript Parse Error**: The JavaScript source code internal in Node's bootstrapping process caused a parse error. This is
>   extremely rare, and generally can only happen during the development
>   of Node itself.
>
> **4 - Internal JavaScript Evaluation Failure**: The JavaScript source code internal in Node's bootstrapping process failed to return a
>   function value when evaluated. This is extremely rare, and generally
>   can only happen during the development of Node itself.
>
> **5 - Fatal Error**: There was a fatal unrecoverable error in V8. Typically, a message will be printed to stderr with the prefix FATAL
>   ERROR.
>
> **6 - Non-function Internal Exception Handler**: There was an uncaught exception, but the internal fatal exception handler function was
>   somehow set to a non-function, and could not be called.
>
> **7 - Internal Exception Handler Run-Time Failure**: There was an uncaught exception, and the internal fatal exception handler function
>   itself threw an error while attempting to handle it.
>
> **8 - Unused**
>
> **9 - Invalid Argument**: Either an unknown option was specified, or an option requiring a value was provided without a value.
>
> **10 - Internal JavaScript Run-Time Failure**: The JavaScript source code internal in Node's bootstrapping process threw an error when the
>   bootstrapping function was called. This is extremely rare, and
>   generally can only happen during the development of Node itself.
>
> **11 - Invalid Debug Argument**: The `--debug` and/or `--debug-brk` options were set, but an invalid port number was chosen
>
> **>128 - Signal Exits**: If Node receives a fatal signal such as `SIGKILL` or `SIGHUP`, then its exit code will be 128 plus the value
>   of the signal code. This is a standard Unix practice, since exit codes
>   are defined to be 7-bit integers, and signal exits set the high-order
>   bit, and then contain the value of the signal code.

**Source:** https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_process.htm

Answer (score 15):

You can find the answer to your question in the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code

Basically if you want to exit with success use 0 if you want to exit with failure use 1.

Answer (score 9):

`0` is a success code and `1` (or another number) can be a failure code.  `0` will be used if nothing is specified.  Useful for passing information on the way out.  Answered on SO here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5266239/5463636

More info direct from the Node.js docs here:

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code