# console.log not working in scripts/deploy.js and in smart_contract in HardHat

Tags: javascript, solidity, console.log, ethers.js, hardhat

console.log not working in **scripts/deploy.js** and **contracts/WavePortal.sol** in Hardhat. When I run the command **npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js** it only shows "" Compiled 1 Solidity file successfully "" .
Its not working in my HardHat environment. Not even when I am using INFURA and running with the command **npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network ropsten**
I searched everywhere from youtube to StackOverflow but didn't got any solution. I only got one hint --->

**Since the contract code is running onchain, you'll see the console.log from the chain output, not in your javascript console output.** But I am not able to get this statement.... Please help me

**scripts/deploy.js**

```
    const [owner, randomPerson] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
    const waveContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("WavePortal");
    const waveContract = await waveContractFactory.deploy();
    await waveContract.deployed();
    
    console.log("Contract deployed to:", waveContract.address);
    console.log("Contract deployed by:", owner.address);
    
    let wavecount;
    wavecount = await waveContract.getTotalWaves();
    
    let waveTxn = await waveContract.wave();
    await waveTxn.wait();

    wavecount = await waveContract.getTotalWaves();

  };
  
  const runMain = async () => {
    try {
      await main();
      process.exit(0); // exit Node process without error
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      process.exit(1); // exit Node process while indicating 'Uncaught Fatal Exception' error
    }
    // Read more about Node exit ('process.exit(num)') status codes here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47163396/7974948
  };
```

**contracts/WavePortal.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract WavePortal {
    uint256 totalWaves;

    constructor() {
        console.log("Yo yo, I am a contract and I am smart");
    }

    function wave() public {
        totalWaves += 1;
        console.log("%s has waved!", msg.sender);
    }

    function getTotalWaves() public view returns (uint256) {
        console.log("We have %d total waves!", totalWaves);
        return totalWaves;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so hard I got the solution. Actually I've installed vs code extension **Hardhat+Solidity** provided by  **Hardhat**  officially. So, I uninstalled it and I installed `Solidity` extension by `Juan Blanco` and I downgraded its version to `v0.0.135` and now its working absolutely fine !!

Answer (score 0):

Did this with a quick test in remix, seems like your smart contract is working fine and prints out the lines.

```
console.log:
 Yo yo, I am a contract and I am smart
 
[vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: WavePortal.(constructor)value: 0 weidata: 0x608...17274logs: 0hash: 0x1d0...16b87
transact to WavePortal.wave pending ... 
console.log:
 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4 has waved!
 
[vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: WavePortal.wave() 0xd91...39138value: 0 weidata: 0x6fe...15b44logs: 0hash: 0xbda...02370
call to WavePortal.getTotalWaves
console.log:
 We have 1 total waves!
```

Your deploy.js looks fine as well. Could be a setting issue apart from code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brother, Actually I've installed vs code extension **Hardhat+Solidity** provided by  **Hardhat**  officially. So, I uninstalled it and I installed `Solidity` extension by Juan Blanco and I downgraded its version to `v0.0.135` and now its working absolutely fine !!