# Port 3000 is already in use [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: javascript, node.js

Port 3000 is already in use:

> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you tried to close and reopen terminals?

Comment: Try to use other port or kill whatever is running on port 3000.

Comment: The problem seems pretty clear - Something is using port 3000. What have you tried ?

Comment: @JaydipJadhav yes, bro there is no any open terminals

Comment: Off topic and should be on serverfault.com but is likely already a duplicate.

Answer (score 35):

### Killing a process that owns port 3000

#### Unix-like operating systems (e.g., GNU/Linux, [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD), and [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS))

First, let’s take a look at how we can kill a process that has a port open.

Using the [lsof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) command, we can retrieve the PID that has the given port:

```
lsof -i :3000 -t
```

Output:

```
12345
```

Then we can kill this process just by doing:

```
kill 12345
```

Let’s turn this into a one-liner:

```
lsof -i :3000 -t | xargs kill
```

If you’re using environment variable to set the server port, we can specify that instead of hard coding our values:

```
lsof -i :${PORT} -t | xargs kill
```

Lastly, we can default to port 3000 if environment variable isn’t set:

```
lsof -i :${PORT:-3000} -t | xargs kill
```

#### Microsoft Windows

Unless you’re running nodemon on [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) (WSL), `lsof` is not available in Windows. However, [netstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) is available in the Windows shell:

```
netstat -ano | findstr :3000
```

This will return the PID of the process that is using up port 3000 which we can use to kill the process using the [tskill](https://ss64.com/nt/tskill.html) command:

```
tskill 12345
```

If all you care about is making sure the process that owns the port is dead without any graceful shutdown, you can disregard the caveat below.

> ##### **Caveat on Windows process kill behaviour**
>
> If your app listens in on `SIGTERM` to shutdown gracefully when nodemon triggers `tskill` command, Windows will unconditionally terminate your process before your app has a chance to fire the `process.on('SIGTERM')` event handler.
>
> More details on this caveat are here:
>
> - [Node.js > Process > Signal Events](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/process.html#process_signal_events)
> - [libuv Documentation](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/499c7976c613ba0291f55d8f2ff69434fbc4c950/include/uv.h#L1686-L1720)

Sometimes the tskill command won't run due to some reasons. You can also use the following command for killing the process after finding the PID from the above *netstat* command:

```
taskkill /F /T /PID 12345
```

### Getting nodemon to execute hooks

Nodemon lets you set up event hooks through *nodemon.json* configuration file:

```javascript
{
  "events": {
    "crash": "sh -c 'lsof -i :${PORT:-3000} -t | xargs kill'"
  }
}
```

This will cause nodemon to execute the `sh -c 'lsof -i :${PORT:-3000} -t | xargs kill` command whenever your application crashes, thereby killing the child process it spawned that’s keeping the port open.

For more information on nodemon events, check out their documentation:

- [Sample nodemon.json](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md)
- [Events](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/wiki/Events)

Comment: how to run "events" for windows? please write windows event too.

Comment: What does 12345 actually stand for? Is that meaning of the folder name?

Comment: No, 12345 is the "pid" (process id) of the current process listening on the given port. With that knowledge, you're now able to kill that process.
@stackunderflow Great answer. Thx

Answer (score 31):

Borrowed from my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59764941/459233):

1. Install the `kill-port` node package as a dev dependency:

   ```sh
   npm install kill-port --save-dev
   ```
2. Create a `nodemon.json` file in the root of your project containing:

   ```json
   {
     "events": {
       "restart": "kill-port 3000",
       "crash": "kill-port 3000"
     },
     "delay": "1500"
   }
   ```
3. Then, in your `package.json` file, have something like this:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
       "start-dev": "nodemon app.js",
   }
   ```
4. Then start your app in dev mode with:

   ```sh
   npm run start-dev
   ```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It is weird, because nodemon was working until today.

Comment: didn't work for me, same situation @TomasLukac

Comment: it works.. but it's not fixing the root cause

Comment: it works like a charm for me, except for having to install `kill-port` as global instead

Comment: Change it to `kill-port --port 3000` if its not working

Answer (score 5):

The *best way* to counter this problem is directly kill the port with the following command.

```
fuser -n tcp -k 3000
```

Comment: But i will need to run this everytime my server restarts! this is even worse than direct node app.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command at terminal to check which process is using that port:

```
netstat -aon | findstr '[port_number]'
```

If that process is not required, you can kill that process and start your own process on port 3000. Otherwise you can always use another port for your application.

Most probably this process will be nodemon, which you can kill and start again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with nodemon continuing to watch for file changes even after I closed the terminal. I stopped all Node.js processes (not just the Node.js process using the port).

Answer (score -2):

It seems that the 3000 port is in use. You can kill the process that is using 3000 port or you can change the port of the node from 3000 to any another port.