# How do i stop a javascript executing?

Tags: javascript

How can i stop executing this Javascript after executing?
Usually this problem is caused because of missing return statements in functions. Well, both functions return something. So why does the Skript continue running and what can i do against it?

```
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;

function hexToRgb(hex) {
  // Expand shorthand form (e.g. "03F") to full form (e.g. "0033FF")
  var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
  hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function(m, r, g, b) {
    return r + r + g + g + b + b;
  });
  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
  return result ? {
    r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
    g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
    b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
  } : null;
}


function rgb2hex(red, green, blue) {
  var rgb = blue | (green << 8) | (red << 16);
  return '#' + (0x1000000 + rgb).toString(16).slice(1)
}



hexPrimaryColor = args[1];
redPrimaryColor = hexToRgb(hexPrimaryColor).r;
greenPrimaryColor = hexToRgb(hexPrimaryColor).g;
bluePrimaryColor = hexToRgb(hexPrimaryColor).b;
redComplimentaryColor = 255 - redPrimaryColor;
greenComplimentaryColor = 255 - greenPrimaryColor;
blueComplimentaryColor = 255 - bluePrimaryColor;
hexCcomplimentaryColor = rgb2hex(redComplimentaryColor, greenComplimentaryColor, blueComplimentaryColor);
//console.log("Primärfarbe:" + hexPrimaryColor +"\n");
console.log(hexCcomplimentaryColor);
//throw Error();
```

Comment: This doesn't solve your answer, but please use indentation

Comment: What do you mean, 'continue running'? Functions, when you call `return`, will return a value to their caller. It's the end of this function, but not the end of the entire script.

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266152/how-to-exit-in-node-js

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `process.exit(0)` to the end of your program

Answer (score 0):

put you  code in a function and call it after return somewhere down

```
condition()
 return; // put your code after return 

callFunction();

function callFunction(){
 hexPrimaryColor = args[1];
 redPrimaryColor = hexToRgb(hexPrimaryColor).r;
 greenPrimaryColor = hexToRgb(hexPrimaryColor).g;
 bluePrimaryColor = hexToRgb(hexPrimaryColor).b;
 redComplimentaryColor = 255 - redPrimaryColor;
 greenComplimentaryColor = 255 - greenPrimaryColor;
 blueComplimentaryColor = 255 - bluePrimaryColor;
 hexCcomplimentaryColor = rgb2hex(redComplimentaryColor, 
 greenComplimentaryColor, blueComplimentaryColor);
 //console.log("Primärfarbe:" + hexPrimaryColor +"\n");
 console.log(hexCcomplimentaryColor);
   //throw Error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. In fact the code was completely fine. I just executed the code with phantomjs and didn't put `phantom.exit()` in the end. Thats why the process didn't stopped.