# How to stop executing my .js app after typing specific command?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This time, I've been doing research over *how to stop executing JS app*. Unfortunately, I didn't find any matching my needs code... Anyway, I want to write function, that stops my app, after typing *close*.After that, main app won't recognize child app's commands, unless you load that child app again.Here's my code:

```
var command = $("input[type='text']").val();

if(command === "close"){
   // Close this app
}
```

**FULL VERSION HERE:** [todo-list on Github](https://github.com/textual-javascript/tjs-app-library/blob/master/apps/todo-list.js)

Comment: reload the page: window.location.reload(true);

Comment: @AlexS. That's not what I want to do, I just want to stop one JS app.

Comment: break, will help you if you want to stop loop

Comment: @manan5439 There's no loop in my app. I'll edit description, so that everyone can have a look at full version of code, if neccesarry.

Comment: There's no such thing as "closing an app" in the browser; either the browser window is open and running, or the window is closed.   If you want to remove a portion of your script that is attached to a particular dom node, remove that dom node or unbind any event triggers that fire the unwanted code.

Comment: @DanielBeck Hmm... that's good point to start with.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean never execute anything in the current page you could use a global variable.

```
stopExec = false;
var command = $("input[type='text']").val();

if(command === "close"){
   // Close this app
   stopExec = true;
}
```

With this now you will have to check in all function the state of `stopExec` like this

```
function foo(){
    if(stopExec === false){
        // code of foo()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set stopExec to true in closeApp, which never called. 
Check my modification to your code.

```
// Add this line
stopExec = true;
else if(command === "close" && stopExec === false){
    closeApp(); 
}

// and in closeApp, you don't need to set stopExec (it wasn't executing before anyway)
    function closeApp(){
     printOut("APP WAS CLOSED", "success")
     stopExec = true
}
```

And, "command" is undefined. You will need to bind "command" to the value of the input when pressing enter like: event.target.value === "close".

Comment: So, I have very simple todo-list app, that is a part of bigger app. Basically, todo-list app has a command _close_, that is supposed to; surprise surprise, close child app. After that, main app won't recognize child app's commands, unless you load that child app again.

Comment: In this context, closing the child app is removing the top level dom node.
Don't forget to unbind any event listeners attached to the removed dom node.

Comment: I'm doing this, and works just fine, but other, unrelated to this problem glitches occured. Still, I can consider it [problem with closing child app] solved.

Comment: Forgot to edit, command is defined in main app `var command = $("input[type='text']").val();`

Comment: Furthermore, this main app isn't avalible anywhere yet, as I'm still working on it. You'll be able to see it on 12th July...

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to improve you code with

```
var command = $("input[type='text']").val();

if(command === "close"){
process.exit()
}
```

here is a link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266152/how-to-exit-in-node-js) for more info

```
 process.exit(1) //return terminate with failure code
 process.exit(0) //return terminate with success  code
```

Comment: you are using node js because it is only work with nodejs  https://nodejs.org/api/

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`

Comment: I'm telling you, I don't need node.js here!

Comment: I think he assumed you were using node because that's the only js context in which "closing an app" (as opposed to just closing the browser window) makes sense.