# Exit the process when multiple async operations completed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to exit node process when all data will be processed (fetch data, http request with axios and update data). When I run my script by typing `node script.js` it never ends. Where should I use process.exit() in my script to be sure all data has been processed? Script below:

```
Keyword.find({
        images: {
            $eq: []
        }
    })
    .limit(8)
    .exec((err, keywords) => {
        keywords.forEach((keyword) => {
            console.log(keyword.body);
            axios.get('https://www.example.com/?q=' + encodeURIComponent(keyword.body))
                .then(function (response) {
                    const dom = new JSDOM(response.data);
                    let items = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('div.item');
                    let images = [];
                    items.forEach(((item) => {
                        let url = item.querySelector('a.thumb').href;
                        let source = item.querySelector('a.tit').href;
                        let description = item.querySelector('div.des').innerHTML;
                        images.push({
                            url,
                            source,
                            description
                        });
                    }));

                    Keyword.findByIdAndUpdate({
                        _id: keyword._id
                    }, {
                        $set: {
                            images
                        }
                    }, (err2, result2) => {
                        if (err2) console.log(err2);
                        console.log(result2);
                    });
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266152/how-to-exit-in-node-js)

Comment: If you're not looking for `process.exit(..)` Nothing in your code indicates you're blocking the runloop, which is why your code don't exit when it's done (assuming you run in a terminal environment, and not Electron et.al.). You should post mode code and rephrase your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your database connection is keeping your app from automatically exit.
So you should either close the database connection or call `process.exit()` when you have done your work.

You are doing multiple async operations simultaneously

```js
keywords.forEach((keyword) => {
    axios.get(...
```

To be notified when all the operations completed you can create a Promise array and listens to them by `Promise.all()` method

```js
const operations = keywords.map((keyword) => axios.get('').then((response) => {
    ...
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Keyword.findByIdAndUpdate(query, update, (err2, result2) => {
            if (err2) {
                console.log(err2);
                reject(err2);
            }
            console.log(result2);
            resolve();
        });
    });
}));

Promise.all(operations).then(()=>{
    console.log('All done.');
    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

The process.exit() method instructs Node.js to terminate the process synchronously with an exit status of code. If code is omitted, exit uses either the 'success' code 0 or the value of process.exitCode if it has been set. Node.js will not terminate until all the 'exit' event listeners are called.

To exit with a 'failure' code:

```
process.exit(1);
```

Comment: I know about process.exit(), but question is where to put this line, to be able to exit AFTER all data will be processed correctly?

Comment: FYI, rather than duplicate answers, it's better to vote to close a question.