# How to exit in Deno? (analog of process.exit)

Tags: typescript, deno

How to exit in [Deno](https://deno.land/) passing a status code?

[In Node.js you could use `process.exit()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266152/how-to-exit-in-node-js), what is its Deno's counterpart ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As of Deno version `0.3.4`:

```
Deno.exit(1); // the exit code is optional and defaults to 0
```

Check out [https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/~/Deno](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/Deno) to know everything that you can access through the `Deno` global.