# how to exit a program reading input from terminal?

Tags: node.js

Am writing a to a file by taking input from terminal. however, when I tried to listen to the text "exit" so that I can exit the program. the listener is not triggered.

I have written the code. I am already getting the input via the terminal and writing to a file. However. I cannot exit the program

```
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./myFile.txt', 'utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', (data, done) => {
    if (data === 'exit') {
        done();
    }
    writeStream.write(data);

});

process.on('exit', () => {
    process.exit();
});
```

from terminal window:
input text to write to file:
1.This is my test text
2. I am writing this to file
3. exit

Expected result: I expect the lines 1 and 2 to be written to file and as soon as the exit word is typed. the program should exit.
Actual:
This is not the case as the word 'exit' is also added to the file and the program refused to exit except I press a key combination of CTRL + C.

Comment: Could it be a matter of newline / carriage return `data == 'exit\n'`?

Answer (score 2):

```
process.stdin.on('data', (data, done) => {
    if (data === 'exit' or data === 'exit\n') { 
        process.exit();
    }else {
        writeStream.write(data);
    }
});
```

you need to wrap the `writeStream.write(data);` in a else statment and use process.exit() instead of done. also look for exit\n not just exit

Comment: @graficode thats the idea, he doesnt want exit to be writen into the file

Comment: It shouldn't write to file if it exts first

Comment: @JimiHunter can you please elaborate? did you receive errors? or did it not do the function it should?

Answer (score 1):

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37592669/7004388). Hope it might help you.

> Calling process.exit() will force the process to exit as quickly as
>   possible even if there are still asynchronous operations pending that
>   have not yet completed fully, including I/O operations to
>   process.stdout and process.stderr.

To properly exit the code while letting the process exit gracefully, edit your code with the below in the `exit` process.

```
if (someConditionNotMet()) {
  printUsageToStdout();  
  process.exitCode = 1;
}
```