# Node.js - process.exit(-1)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found a lot of information about the node.js process.exit(), and different numbers are being passed. But I have a legacy project where they have used `process.exit(-1)` all over the codebase. I couldn't find any information about the exit code `-1`. There is 0 or 1 or any other number but not any negative number. It would be beneficial to find out what it is all about. Thanks a lot

Comment: There is no relevance to the value being a negative or a positive. That just represents the return value of your app. You can check the return value of your app after it exits, to see if it ended with an error or successfully.

Comment: So the numbers are being passed has point? What number would you recommend as a best practice?

Comment: Only if you are handling the numbers outside the app itself.

Comment: I would use negative values to signify errors and 0 for success and other positive numbers for success with specific other messages.

Comment: Perfect. thanks a lot

Comment: In Windows, batch files work a lot simpler if you use `0` for regular success and something greater than 0 for other conditions that you want to check for.  Windows does not like negative numbers for exit codes.  They can be used, but then built-in batch file operations like `IF ERRORLEVEL 1` won't work.

Comment: Can I write it as an answer, and would you mind accepting it?

Comment: Please take a look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418784/what-is-the-min-and-max-values-of-exit-codes-in-linux)

Comment: @Shlang That was very helpful. 0 to 255 and -1 means 255. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a negative exit code. The minimum is `0` and the maximum is `255` aka `-1`

So when you write `process.exit(-1)` you are actually writing `process.exit(255)`

Comment: Well thanks a lot. What exit code would you recommend as a best practice for a regular code or connection related error?

Comment: Here's a list of error codes you could use for network related errors: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRBY/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.messages.doc/doc/r0058740.html

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to be correct. I can return any error code using Node.js in the range *-2147483648 to 2,147,483,647* and it will be returned properly in the batch file that called the Node.js program. Any number out of that range just loops back round, so that it is in the range.

Comment: Other numbers [other than 0-255] can be used, but these are treated modulo 256, so exit -10 is equivalent to exit 246, and exit 257 is equivalent to exit 1.
https://www.shellscript.sh/exitcodes.html